# Match lines until certain set of characters in vim

Tags: vim

```
{hola}

{   
    \defn{[34,\cite{Lint:1998:ICT:552386}]}                                                                                                                      
\[
    R\coloneqq n^{-1}\log_2|\code|                                                                                                                            
\]
is called the rate of $\code$                                                                                                                                 
}
```

I need to match all inside the string "{
        \defn{[34,\cite{Lint:1998:ICT:552386}]}  " and the last character }. Could you help me please?

I am trying this

```
{\n.*\\defn{\[\d\+,\s*\\cite{.\+}]}\_.\+\n}\}
```

but this does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This question should probably go on the [vi and vim site](https://vi.stackexchange.com)...*

---

Your regex has many many problems.

1. There is whitespace after the first `{` character, so the `{\n` part will never ever match. Try deleting this whitespace or adding `\s*`
2. You probably don't want to use `.\+`, because this will match more than necessary, likely causing some false positives. You probably want `.\{-}`, because this is a *non-greedy* qualifier, which means it will always match as little as possible. Without this, you will match lines such as

   ```
   \defn{[34,\cite{Lint:1998:ICT:552386 \\hello world \\here's a bunch of random crap you don't want to match ]}]} }]}
   ```
3. You most definitely do not want to use `\_.\+` because this will match everything until the end of the file. From `:h \_.`

   ```
                               */\_.*
   \_. Matches any single character or end-of-line.
       Careful: "\_.*" matches all text to the end of the buffer!
   ```

   Again, you want the non-greedy quantifier, `\_.\{-}`
4. Why are you trying to match 2 `}` characters at the end? Your text clearly only ends with one.
5. You do not need to escape a `}` character.

Putting this all together, try using this regex instead:

```
{.*\n.*\\defn{\[\d\+,\s*\\cite{.\{-}}]}\_.\{-}\n}
```